# Speed difference when using different values with modulo

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm using gcc 4.6.3 and creating a large array of random shorts. I'm generating them with the following statements:

```
val = SHRT_MAX; //as defined by limits.h
while(array<end) {
    *array++ = rand() % val;
}
```

This is a considerably fast operation, and even for arrays as large as 5,000,000 elements is completed almost instantly. I was curious about my sorts efficiency with a smaller variation in numbers and changed that to:

```
val = 3;
```

This caused a considerable speed difference, it ran much slower than the original statements. What is it that is causing such a considerable speed difference?

Comment: Two words: Compiler Optimizations. Some moduli are easier to mod by than others.

Comment: Just as a remark, taking the modulus of an uniformly distributed random number doesn't necessarily produce uniformly distributed random numbers in a range.

Comment: @honk - Could you expand on that (or link to an explanation)? I don't understand why that would be the case.

Comment: @GordonBailey: This almost is a FAQ regarding random numbers here. See http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx for some detailed explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range-c is an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SHRT_MAX` is most likely greater than or equal to `RAND_MAX`. The statement:

```
*array++ = rand() % val;
```

can be optimized into:

```
int rand_value= rand();
if (rand_value==RAND_MAX) rand_value= 0;
*array++= rand_value;
```

which is faster because it replaces a modulus with a branch. The second version, where `val` is 3, cannot be optimized into a simpler version that runs without modulus.

`% SHRT_MAX` cannot be simplified into a bitwise operation. But combined with knowledge of how `rand()` is specified, the compiler can certainly optimize statements dealing with `rand()` and values greater than or equal to `RAND_MAX`.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers can optimize calculation of modulo (a%B), where B is a constant. It replaces actual modulo with simpler arithmetic operations. The details are explained in topics like [Most optimized way to calculate modulus in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661697/most-optimized-way-to-calculate-modulus-in-c). However such optimizations are faster for some values of B than for others.

Even CPU division/modulo instruction can take different number of cycles complete (at least on some CPUs). See numbers for x86 here: http://gmplib.org/~tege/x86-timing.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

SHRT_MAX is a `2^n-1` value, which can be optimised for divide. Dividing by 3 is much tougher, so the compiler may well decide to divide by 3 (or do some other magic operation that is slower than the `2^n-1` variant.

The fastest modulo you can use is for `2^n`, which can be replaced with a single and-instruciton, for positive values: `x % 256` is the same as `x & 255`. Unfortunately, when the value may be negative, it's not quite so easy...

Comment: 3 is also `2^n - 1` (`n` = 2).